# The character ' causing jump to login page in ASP.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, submit, pageload

I have an asp.net website with C#. 
I have found out a problem that the character ' causes a reroute to login page. If the text in a **textbox** is like **abc's car** it causes jump to the login page when the form is submitted using button whereas if the text is changed to **car of abc** it behaves normal. 
Also this problem is not occurring in all ISP.
Secondly, there is a jump to the login page but actually it is not logged out. The session is still active if we press the back button it works normal.

Moreover, if the aspx file contains **'** like **chairman's comment** in a label then the page wont load and causes a reroute to login page

can anybody help me
here is the code for one of the textbox:

```
 <td style="width: 522px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTP" runat="server" Height="90px" TextMode="MultiLine" onDrop="return false;"
                onKeyPress="return limitCharsLength(this,2000);" onPaste="return limitCharsLength(this,2000);" onCopy="return false" oncut="return false"
                Width="100%" AutoPostBack="True" ontextchanged="TextBoxTP_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxTP_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBoxTP"  WatermarkText="Enter text here. Use indirect form wihtout addressing the candidate." WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter your comments about Teaching Performance"
                ControlToValidate="TextBoxTP"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br/>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please write one or two sentences"
                OnServerValidate="ValidateTextLength" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTextLength"
                ControlToValidate="TextBoxTP"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelPrTP" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
```

here is the Javascript used:

```
function limitCharsLength(Object, MaxLen) {
if (Object.value.length > MaxLen - 1) {
    Object.value = Object.value.substring(0, MaxLen);
}
}
function limitClipBoard(Object, MaxLen) {
if (window.clipboardData != null) {
    //alert("clipboardData  is not null");
    if (window.clipboardData.getData("Text").length > MaxLen - 1 - 
Object.value.length) {
      //  alert("clipboardData  is very big");
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", 
window.clipboardData.getData("Text").toString().substring(0, (MaxLen - 
Object.value.length)));
        }
    }
}

function ValidateTextLength(oSrc, args) {
     args.IsValid = args.Value.length > 10;}
```

Comment: You are definitely going in the wrong direction if you think that some character in your input box is redirecting to your login page. please check your site properly.Show us some code so that we may be able to help.

Comment: This is not normal behavior. This is something you've coded. You'll need to make a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. The issue was that the network security was bypassing the load-balancer from the firewall. when the server requests goes through the load balancer it takes care of such vulnerabilities and treat apostrophy(')  as text.